# Best way to import several classes

Tags: python, class, import

I have defined several classes in a single python file. My wish is to create a library with these. I would ideally like to import the library in such a way that I can use the classes without a prefix (like mylibrary.myclass() as opposed to just myclass() ), if that's what you can call them, I am not entirely sure as I am a beginner.

What is the proper way to achieve this, or the otherwise best result? Define all classes in __init __? Define them all in a single file as I currently have like AllMyClasses.py? Or should I have a separate file for every class in the library directory like FirstClass.py, SecondClass.py etc.

I realize this is a question that should be easy enough to google, but since I am still quite new to python and programming in general I haven't quite figured out what the correct keywords are for a problem in this context(such as my uncertainty about "prefix")

Answer (score 2):

More information can be found in the tutorial on [modules](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#) (single files) or [packages](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages) (when in a directory with an `__init__.py` file) on the python site.

The suggested way (according to [the style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports)) is to spell out each class import specifically.

```
from my_module import MyClass1, MyClass2
object1 = MyClass1()
object2 = MyClass2()
```

While you can also shorten the module name:

```
import my_module as mo
object = mo.MyClass1()
```

Using `from my_module import *` is recommended to be avoided as it can be confusing (even if it is the recommended way for some things, like `tkinter`)

Answer (score 1):

If it's for your personal use, you can just put all your classes `Class1`, `Class2`, ... in a `myFile.py` and to use them call `import myFile` (without the `.py` extension)

```
import myFile

myVar1 = myFile.Class1()
myVar2 = myFile.Class2()
```

from within another script. If you want to be able to use the classes without the file name prefix, import the file like this:

```
from myFile import *
```

Note that the file you want to import should be in a directory where Python can find it (the same where the script is running or a directory in `PYTHONPATH`).

The `_init_` is needed if you want to create a Python module for distribution. Here are the instructions: [Distributing Python Modules](https://docs.python.org/3/distributing/index.html)

EDIT after checking the Python's style guide PEP 8 [on imports](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports):

> *Wildcard imports (from* `import`*) should be avoided, as they make it unclear which names are present in the namespace, confusing both readers and many automated tools*

So in this example you should have used

```
from myFile import Class1, Class2
```